# How do i have my product home page back on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am building an eCommerce website with WordPress Version 4.9.6 using woo Commerce Version 3.4.2 , I was trying to customize shipment method, so i enabled debug mode in Delivery options *(_woo Commerce settings _)*.

After that, my web site just display a blog page instead of my products, as you can see on this link [my home page](https://mtamarket.com)

even after deactivating the debug mode, i still have the same result.
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to re-define it?

While logged-in, and while in the Home Page, go to customize in the upper-bar  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WDEf.jpg

Then go to Homepage settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZdcc.jpg

There you can make again the page you want as Main. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFTg.jpg

if that not solve it, try to give more information about your Woocommerce Setup, otherwise if my answer solve it, please consider mark this as an answer.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. Which details do you really need ?

Comment: ¿What is defined as shop page in Woocommerce->Settings->Products->General?